# Windows nxlog - Wildcard Directories in Config File

Tags: nxlog

I have the following folder structure:

```
-job-folders
    -1
        -log.txt
    -2
        -log.txt
    -3  
        -log.txt
```

I want to do watch `log.txt` in all of the above job folders.  I am currently using:

```
<Input my-log>
    Module im_file
    File "C:\job-folders\*\log.txt"  
    SavePos TRUE
    Recursive TRUE
</Input>
```

In `nxlog.log`, I get

```
2015-12-21 12:10:25 ERROR apr_stat failed on file C:\job-folders\*\log.txt; The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

I know it says explicitly that directory names cannot be wildcarded at https://nxlog.co/docs/en/nxlog-reference-manual.html#im_file_config_file

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The pattern I was looking for was

`File "C:\job-folders\\\*log.txt"`

Comment: With the Recursive option enabled (which is the default) it will look into subfolders for "*log.txt"

Comment: The same works for linux based installations too. Setting the file path to /var/log/elasticsearch/*ecs_product_head_index_search_slowlog.log in the configuration did the trick.

Comment: Thanks @Lloyd you helped me a lot. Nxlog be like : "oh you just need to escape 11 times to make it works, have you tried \\\\\\\\\\*.txt ?"